# How does epoll know socket is ready in kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, epoll

I didn't find any hints in `epool` source code about how epoll knows socket is ready for `read/write`.

1. Does epoll register a `callback` in the kernel?
2. Does epool register a `signal` in the kernel for `read/write`?
3. Or something else?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer

Not only for `epoll` but in general for "blocking I/O" (the same mechanism is used by `read()` syscall, for example), kernel uses `waitqueues` (don't confuse them with `workqueues` which is totally different mechanism). If you check `ep_poll()` implementation, it's even documented in comments.

#### Some not-so-interesting details

In order to put current thread to sleep on waitqueue, one would normally use `wait_event_interruptible()` call. `epoll_wait` does not do that, however. Instead it kind off re-implements what this call would do by adding itself to the waitqueue with `__add_wait_queue_exclusive()`, putting itself to sleep with `set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE)` and checking what was the cause of being woken up in a loop. The end result is the same - the current thread will be put to interruptible sleep which may be terminated either by sending signal (in which case `epoll_wait` will return `EINTR`) or when woken up by `ep_poll_callback` through `waitqueues` mechanism.